# Why do I have to repeat input before it will let me move on?

Tags: java, arrays, input

When i go to add an employee this code first prompts for a new employee ID. It then checks the arrays to make sure that that ID has not already been used. the problem i am having is that it makes me type the ID twice before moving on to the rest of the feilds. The other fields only have to be input one time. I can not figure out what is causing it. Can you guys help point me in the right direction.

Example output:

```
Please enter the maximum number of employees for your store

2

Welcome to the employee management system

a) Add a new Employee

b) Delete an Employee

c) Print the Employee List

d) Print a Specific Employee

e) Exit the Employee Management System

a

Please enter the employee ID.

1234  //should only have to type it in once but as you can see in the example i have to type it a second time 
             //before it moves on

1234

Please enter the employee name.
```

I think the problem is in the method below.

```
public void addEmployee() // choice a
{
    int id = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;      
    while (x < maxEmployees && empNumber[x] != 0) // allows user to add employee as long as x is less than maxEmployees and empNumber in next array is 0
        x++;

    if(x == maxEmployees)// tells user that they can not add more employees if they have too many before kicking them back to the menu
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to add more employees. Max number of employees reached.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the employee ID.");
        id = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        while (y < maxEmployees && empNumber[y] != id) // checks to see if employee id already exsist
            y++;
        if(y == maxEmployees) // if no matching id is found continues the adding process
        {
            empNumber[x] = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the employee name.");
            empName[x] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the employee address.");
            empAddress[x] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the employee salary.");
            empSalary[x] = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        }

        else
            System.out.println("This ID is already associated with an employee");
    }
```

Comment: You should consider marking the answer as correct if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are asking the user to input an id twice.

First time is here:

```
id = scan.nextInt();
nothing = scan.nextLine();
```

Second time is here:

```
empNumber[x] = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Try

```
empNumber[x] = id;
```

in place of

```
empNumber[x] = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```